The cordova-plugin-qr-barcode-scanner plugin is having problems creating APK builds after updating to Android 14 (SDK 34)
My project uses meteor js version 2.5.3 and I recently updated my apk target sdk version to 34, after making these changes, I was unable to build the APK.
The build was successful after removing a cordova plugin (cordova-plugin-qr-barcode-scanner@8.0.3).
This is the error that occurred when using the plugin:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does. ```

